# confusion_matrix, ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (2, 2)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I used the code below in order to visualize the confusion matrix in python, it throws an exception:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (2, 2)

```
if_cm=confusion_matrix(y_test, preds)
import seaborn as sns
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(if_cm, ['True Normal','True Anomaly'],['Pred Normal','Pred Anomaly'])
pyplot.figure(figsize = (8,4))
sns.set(font_scale=1.4)#for label size
sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16},fmt='g')# font size
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Please paste the content of y_test and preds here.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('db.csv')/
y_true=df['Target']/
df_data=df.drop('Target',1)/                                                                        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_data, y_true, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)/                                                                                                   preds = alg.predict(X_test)